# Java код: в чем проблема?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с кодом? Компилятор пишет, что сборка завершена без проблем, но результат не выводится.

```
class Ex{
     public static void main(String args[]){
        int num;
        num = 100;
        System.out.println("This s num: " + num);
        num = num * 2;
        System.out.print("This valie of num * 2 is ");
        System.out.println(num);
        }
```

Comment: @Djamadhar, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: >Компилятор пишет, что сборка завершена без проблем, но результат не выводится.

Ну вообще-то кроме сборки надо еще и запускать - не пробовали?

Comment: javac ex. Вроде бы так надо запустить.

Comment: @Deadkenny только java ex

Comment: Кстати, в таком виде и сборка не может быть завершена - закрывающей скобки класса нет.

Comment: У меня в Eclipse всё прекрасно работает! 

Answer (score 5):

Если добавить закрывающую скобку класса, всё работает.
Единственное, этот код можно существенно упросить:

```
class Ex{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num = 100;
        System.out.println("This s num: " + num);
        num *= 2;
        System.out.println("This valie of num * 2 is " + num);
    }
}
```

1. Объявление и присвоение для локальной переменной `num` можно
   объединить в одно действие.
2. В Java есть операторы с присвоением (`*=`, `+=` , `-=`, `/=` и
   `%=`), которые упрощают запись команд типа `num = num * 2`.
3. Последние 2 строки метода `main()`, где Вы выводите удвоенную
   переменную лучше объединить в одну. Всё равно ведь создаются 2
   объекта. Чтобы создавался один объект, конкатенацию строк лучше
   проводить через `StringBuilder`, правда в случае с двумя строками
   такая оптимизация смысла не имеет.

Comment: Upd если автору важен переход на следующую строку, забыли дописать про `"\n"`

 `System.out.println("This valie of num * 2 is " +  "\n" + num);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int num = 100;
    System.out.println(num);
    num = num * 2;
    System.out.println(num);
}
```